# get count() in a groupBy with two facts

Tags: optaplanner

how can i have the result of a count in a groupBy with two facts.

Context :

```
    private Constraint exampleConstraint(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
    return constraintFactory
            .from(Journey.class)
            .filter((Journey1) -> journey1.isValid())
            .join(Journey.class, Joiners.filtering((Journey1, Journey2) -> (
                    Journey2.getDayJava().equals(Journey1.getDayJava()) && Journey2.isValid()
                    )))
            .groupBy((Journey1, Journey2) ->  Journey2,
                    (Journey1,Journey2) -> ConstraintCollectors.count())
            .penalizeConfigurable(MY_CONSTRAINT, (Journey2, resultOfCount) -> Journey2.getDelta() - resultOfCount);
}
```

Sample of my problem:

```
 .groupBy((journey1, journey2) ->  journey2,
                    (journey1,journey2) -> ConstraintCollectors.count())
```

The second group return me a  ***org.optaplanner.core.api.score.stream.uni.UniConstraintCollector*** but i need an ***int*** or a ***Long***.

Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code snippet shows a misunderstanding of the concept.

First of all, constraint collectors aren't used as a group key, they are used as a standalone argument. Second, `ConstraintCollectors.count()` will not work with a `BiConstraintStream`. For that, you have to use `ConstraintCollectors.countBi()`.

Putting it all together, the corrected code snippet looks like this:

```
private Constraint exampleConstraint(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
    return constraintFactory
        .from(Journey.class)
        .filter((Journey1) -> journey1.isValid())
        .join(Journey.class, 
            Joiners.filtering((Journey1, Journey2) -> 
                Journey2.getDayJava().equals(Journey1.getDayJava()) && Journey2.isValid()))
        .groupBy((Journey1, Journey2) ->  Journey2,
             ConstraintCollectors.countBi())
        .penalizeConfigurable(MY_CONSTRAINT, (Journey2, resultOfCount) -> Journey2.getDelta() - resultOfCount);
}
```

However, there is also a potential for considerable performance improvement here. The `filtering()` joiner is not indexed, and there is a way of replacing it with a fully indexed operation like so:

```
private Constraint exampleConstraint(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
    return constraintFactory.from(Journey.class)
        .filter(Journey::isValid)
        .join(
            constrainFactory.forEach(Journey.class)
                .filter(Journey::isValid), 
            Joiners.equal(Journey::getDayJava))
        .groupBy((Journey1, Journey2) ->  Journey2,
             ConstraintCollectors.countBi())
        .penalizeConfigurable(MY_CONSTRAINT, (Journey2, resultOfCount) -> Journey2.getDelta() - resultOfCount);
}
```

As you can see, I did two things:

- I pre-filtered the stream coming into the join.
- I replaced the remaining part of the `filtering()` joiner with an `equals()` joiner, which is fully indexed.

This way, you should get the most performance out of your constraint.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, effectively i missunderstood the concept of the groupBy(). I'll try to improve performances of my others constraints by your tip. Thanx again, all worked for me :)